# How can I differentiate between B2B and B2C?

Tags: magento2, checkout, price

I would like that in some step of purchase of Magento 2.2.4 could filter depending on the price that is in the cart and ask me some fields or not, I make an example:

- Final Client B2C: When the purchase is over € 1000 you have to apply for the DNI / NIF or to register. We go for purchases over € 1000 that the user is registered, a user "guest" can not make a purchase over € 1000
- B2B final client: When the purchase is over € 100, the user will be more sure to ask for the de-taxing of the order, which is why the CIF would be necessary and oblige him to register.

Therefore, it will always be differentiate what kind of user it is and what rule to apply according to the user, as far as I understand.

What I have not seen any extension information let do that. I do not know if you could help me or give me another option on how to do it

Thank you,

Comment: customer groups

Comment: Can you give me more info please? @PhilippSander

Comment: this is basic. you can get plenty of information by googling